# how can i send emails including html to using php and gmail smtp?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

im using phpmailer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an example that deals exactly with your request.

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleagmail

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use Mail library from PEAR.

Comment: Certainly a possible solution, but as the OP is already noted as using PHPMailer, it is much better to try and either provide a solution using that framework, or direct the OP to a resource on same.